# Accesing JobContext from a partitioned step in JSR 352

Tags: java, batch-processing, glassfish-4

I'm trying to pass an object between batchlets, but I've encountered a problem when trying to access the jobContext from a partitioned step (batchlet).

According to the JSR 352 Specification

> 9.4.1.1 Batch Context Lifecycle and Scope:
>   A batch context has thread affinity and is visible only to the batch 
>   artifacts executing on that particular thread. A batch context injected 
>   field may be null when out of scope. Each context type has a distinct 
>   scope and lifecycle as follows:
>   1. JobContext
>   There is one JobContext per job execution. It exists for the life of a 
>   job. **There is a distinct JobContext for each sub-thread of a parallel 
>   execution (e.g. partitioned step).**
>   2. StepContext
>   There is one StepContext per step execution. It exists for the life of 
>   the step. For a partitioned step, there is one StepContext for the 
>   parent step/thread; there is a distinct StepContext for each sub-thread.

My (failed) solution was to use the JobContext.setTransientUserData, but because the partitioned step uses a distinct JobContext I can't get the TransientUserData.

Is there an alternative to what I'm trying to do? Using PartitionMapper properties it's not possible because I need to pass an object, not a string to every partition.

To be clear, I need to do this:

1. ***NormalBatchlet -> Save an object to be used in the next step.***
2. ***PartitionedBatchlet -> Obtain the saved object in previous step. This object isn't a simple String so using PartitionMapper properties is not a solution.***

**UPDATE**

I'm now using a simple Singleton EJB with a HashMap to store objects between steps and when the job is finished I  clear this map to avoid resources leak.

This is a workaround because I really want to use only the javax.batch package and not depend on EJB's, so I'm not putting it as an answer.

Comment: Don't know how it is defined in JSR, but in *Spring Batch* you can get `JobExecutionContext` (*shared*, I believe) from `StepContext`. And `StepContext` can either be injected in *step scoped* bean  or you can access it from `StepSynchronizationManager`.

Comment: Sadly, I'm using JSR 352 in glassfish 4, not spring batch

Comment: In JBoss 7 / WildFly all partitions will see the same JobContext object, and each one will have a separate StepContext.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like this which should conform with the current spec programming model.

Store the object from your first step using the persistent step data in your NormalBatchlet:

```
stepCtx.setPersistentUserData(mySerializableData);
```

Retrieve the data from the first step in your partitions,  by looking up the previous step:

```
Long execId = jobCtx.getExecutionId();

List<StepExecution> stepExecs = jobOperator.getStepExecutions(execID);

MyPersistentUserData myData;

for (StepExecution step : stepExecs) {
    if (step.getStepName().equals("somePreviousStepX") {
        myData = (MyPersistentUserData)step.getPersistentUserData();
    }
}

//use myData
```

Comment: Very nice hack.  Wish we didn't have to do this.  Seems like a huge gap that isn't addressed by this inability to get the parent job transient data.  I also assume that we would be completely incapable of setting any job transient data in there as the object is completely separate.

Comment: same solution, using a stream instead of for loop:
`myData = (MyPersistentUserData) stepExecs.stream().filter(step -> step.getStepName().equals("somePreviousStepX")).findFirst().orElse(null);`

Answer (score 1):

There is not a spec-defined way to share the transient user data between the JobContext of the main thread and the partition-level JobContext(s).  This is an understandable point of confusion, but this is indeed the intended design.

Comment: But, according to spec:

**_9.5.3 PartitionCollector Interface
A partition collector provides a way to send data from individual partitions to a single point of control running on the parent thread. The PartitionAnalyzer is used to receive and process this data._**

Isn't this the reverse of what I'm trying? I need to pass an object from step1 (normal batchlet) to step2 (partitioned batchlet)

Comment: I'll edit the question because it's not clear in that point after reading it :-P Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In specification mentioned an only one way to access to Context - Injection. See paragraph 9.4.1.

"9.4.1 Batch Contexts

Batch artifact access to batch contexts is by injection using the standard @Inject annotation (javax.inject.Inject). A field into which a batch context is injected must not be static and must not be final.

E.g.:

@Inject JobContext _jctxt;

@Inject StepContext _sctxt;

The batch runtime is responsible to ensure the correct context object is injected according to the job or step currently executing."

Comment: A good example of usage of JSR 352 could be found here https://github.com/radcortez/wow-auctions