# pass object between steps in Java EE batch

Tags: java

How to pass object parameter (not a String, but a List of objects for example) from step 1 to step 2 in Java EE batch job (not a spring-batch job!).

I've tried 2 solutions:

- 1 - using `jobContext`. *i. e*.

  - In step 1:

    ```
    jobContext.setTransientUserData("dataFromSubscribersManager");
    ```
  - In step 2:

    ```
    jobContext.getTransientUserData()
    ```
- 2 - using `dynamic job parameters` *.i. e.*

  ```
  Properties jobParameters = new Properties();
  jobParameters.put("objectToPass", "someObjectToPass");
  jobOperator.start("someJobName", jobParameters);
  ```

  but here we can pass only String type object.

**I need to pass non String object. How to do it?**

Comment: What is the problem with using `setTransientUserData()`?

Comment: In your example, you stored the String "dataFromSubscribersManager" in step 1, so you should obtain that string in Step 2.
You can pass other object types this way.

Comment: On the other hand, Properties by design have such restrictions:
``Properties are configuration values managed as key/value pairs. In each pair, the key and value are both String values.``  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Some JSR 352 implementations, as JBeret (in WildFly/JBoss), will completely ignore any non-String value in the job parameters Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this problem seems similar:

[Accesing JobContext from a partitioned step in JSR 352](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306200/accesing-jobcontext-from-a-partitioned-step-in-jsr-352)

One thing that bothers me in the above solution is the usage of:

```
step.setPersistentUserData(obj);
```

Which means your object (obj - may be large piece of data) might be written in tables in which batch framework keeps its internal information about jobs - if U need it to be persistent that's fine but if U don't that's a drawback.

From jsr-352 [docs](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/batch-1_0-fr-eval-spec/JSR-352-1.0-Final-Release.pdf):

> The setPersistentUserData method stores a persistent data object
>      into the current step. The user data type must implement
>      java.util.Serializable. This data is saved as part of a step's
>      checkpoint. For a step that does not do checkpoints, it is saved
>      after the step ends. It is available upon restart.

As a simpler but not 'jsr-352 style' solution (an alternative to 'Singleton EJB with a HashMap' from above post) I would suggest creating static Map field with synchronized access or Hashtable that would keep the necessary data. This solution however strongly depends on how intensively U will use that Map. Synchronized means other threads will have to wait for acquiring access to Map so U need to analyze possible critical scenarios that the threads will not block each other.

@Singleton EJB has build-in synchronization mechanism:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipsz/index.html

but in this case I don't think it's necessary to use EJB technology - maybe it's a matter of taste.

Comment: But the original question cites the usage of transient, not persistent data: `jobContext.getTransientUserData(obj)`